# String data from serial fails to be parsed as JSON

Tags: android, json, arduino, serial-port

I am building a device that can communicate between a vehicle ECU, Arduino, and Android device. The end goal is to get information from the car to the user's phone.

I currently have the following Arduino code that collects vehicle data via the OBD-II port and sends over the serial as JSON:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <OBD.h>

COBDI2C obd;

char vin[64];
int distance;
int velocity;
int runtime;

String json;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  obd.begin();
  while(!obd.init());
}

void loop() {
  obd.getVIN(vin, sizeof(vin));
  delay(100);
  obd.readPID(PID_DISTANCE, distance);
  delay(100);
  obd.readPID(PID_SPEED, velocity);
  delay(100);
  obd.readPID(PID_RUNTIME, runtime);
  delay(100);

  json = "{\"vin\":\"";
  json.concat(vin);
  json.concat("\",\"distance\":\"");
  json.concat(distance);
  json.concat("\",\"speed\":\"");
  json.concat(velocity);
  json.concat("\",\"runtime\":\"");
  json.concat(runtime);
  json.concat("\"}");

  Serial.print(json);
  delay(5000);
}
```

This would print a string such as `"{\"vin\":\"3VWJM71K89M02\",\"distance\": \"19478\",\"speed\":\"0\",\"runtime\":\"216\"}"` over a USB connection to an Android device. I have a method that is called on the Android device when USB activity occurs:

```
public void onReceivedData(byte[] result) {
     String dataStr;
     try {
         dataStr = new String(result, "UTF-8");
         dataStr = dataStr.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\s]+", "");
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
         driveData = new JSONObject(dataStr);
         updateVehicle(driveData);
     } catch(JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

For some reason, the resulting byte array can be converted into a string with no errors, yet is oddly populated with random line breaks and whitespaces, which is why I used `replaceAll()` to remove these. When I try to create a `JSONObject` from the string (using the `org.json` library) I get errors. However, when I append the original string to a textView, I get something that appears to be very valid JSON:

```
{"vin":"3VWJM71K89M02","distance":"19478","speed":"0","runtime":"216"}
```

Next, I tried constructing a `JSONObject` using the exact string constructed on the Arduino earlier, such as so:

```
 try {
     driveData = new JSONObject("{\"vin\":\"3VWJM71K89M02\",\"distance\": \"19478\",\"speed\":\"0\",\"runtime\":\"216\"}");
     updateVehicle(driveData);
 } catch(JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

This threw me no errors at all. So what am I doing wrong that the original data sent via USB is not as valid as actual data that arrives?

**Update:**
By request I have some error codes from the Android device. Unfortunately, it seems like a chain reaction, so I am providing some of the first ones:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 4 of {"vi
org.json.JSONException: End of character input at character 0 of
org.json.JSONException: Value n" of typejava.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
org.json.JSONException: End of character input at character 0 of
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 7 of "3VMJM7
org.json.JSONException: ...
```

Comment: Post the error log too

Comment: Since I had to use USB for debug, I could not have access to the error logger. The errors I provided are what I copied from a textView on my phone.

Comment: One can run `adb logcat` over TCP, e.g. using wifi. This also allows debugging apps.

Comment: Serial is sending a stream of bytes not messages.

Comment: @gre_gor Yes, the raw USB data is an array of bytes, but I constructed a string out of said data.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that you are not guaranteed to get the full "message" in a single `onReceivedData` call. The first thing to do after the parsing fails is to print out the JSON string to see what it actually is.

Comment: I provided exactly what my data looked like after being converted to a string when appended to a `textView` (code block after the first java block).

Comment: Are you sure that `onReceivedData` wasn't just called multiple times and you saw a completed JSON string?

Comment: I will check if the full string is captured in a single call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gre_gor mentioned in the comments, the event receiving the USB data was not capturing the entire message from the Arduino in a single call. I found that if you keep a running string of the all the USB data and check that string for JSON syntax each call, you eventually get a valid JSON object. Then just reset the string and keep listening.

So, my new code would look like:

```
public String usbStr = "";
public JSONObject driveData;

...

public void onReceivedData(byte[] result) {
     String dataStr;
     try {
         dataStr = new String(result, "UTF-8");
         dataStr = dataStr.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\s]+", "");
         usbStr = usbStr.concat(dataStr);
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
         driveData = new JSONObject(dataStr);
         usbStr = "";
         updateVehicle(driveData);
     } catch(JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a predictable pattern in how USB data is captured. Standard max number of bytes per call? Standard max capture time per call (meaning higher baud would capture more bytes)?